# When using OpenDS for SMTP account status notification, how do I include user's name in notification?

Tags: opends

We are using OpenDS for SMTP account status notification to notify users when their password is nearing expiration. The SMTP account status notification handler works fine to notify the user and a list of Server admins when the password is soon to expire but we are not able to find a way to have the customer's name in the email.

The notification Handler has no issue pulling the customer's email address and also referencing the password policy to correctly identify the pending password expiriation, so why not also identify the customer by name in the email? All this information is available so how would a variable be set to pull and use this customer information?

Answer (score 0):

The notification handlers are quite powerful but definitely under-documented.
It's possible to identify the user by mail in the email. I've looked at the code of OpenDJ (the actively developed branch of OpenDS, http://opendj.forgerock.org), and you can reference any attribute from the user entry within the template.

More specifically for the mail attribute of the user, you should use this property in the template (templates are under config/message/ directory) :
%%notification-user-attr:mail%%

I haven't tested, but it should work.
I hope this helps.

Ludovic Poitou

PS: I've been told by our technical writer, that all tokens that can be used in the template messages is actually documented as part of OpenDJ administration guide : http://opendj.forgerock.org/doc/admin-guide/index.html#account-status-notification